# Is the term “latent effect” in statistics has the same meaning as “latent variable”?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian, latent-variable, latent-class, inla

Is the term “latent effect” in statistics has the same meaning as “latent variable”? If not, then what would be its substantive interpretation?

UPDATE:

There is a whole class of models called “Latent Gaussian models”, and that is where my confusion comes from. Basically, any article/book on Bayesian-hierarchical regression modeling mentions “latent effects”.
Below I have attached the picture of one article where this term is kind of introduced.
The link to the whole article is here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.07844.pdf (hope it opens).

[image]

Comment: Can you include a citation or example of where the term latent effect has been used?

Comment: @ErikRuzek, updated the question

Comment: @ErikRuzek, any thoughts on it?

Comment: I believe these terms are referring to different things, but I am not familiar with the latent effects term whereas I am very familiar with latent variables. I am sorry. Given you are looking at papers using INLA, I would suggest posting this question to their discussion board (https://groups.google.com/g/r-inla-discussion-group).

Comment: @ErikRuzek Thanks, your answer is already very helpful! 
Unfortunately, INLA discussion board is unlikely to answer such a dumb question, as they usually discuss coding and math issues)
So in latent variable modeling it is not typical to refer to the effect of a latent variable as “latent effect”? This is what I, as a layperson, would simply think of)

Comment: I would only talk about a latent effect if I were considering a regression of one latent variable on another, for example in a structural equation model. But again, I'm not convinced they are using that term in the same way.